# Rails 6 | PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at end of input | activerecord-reputation-system gem | Postgresql 12.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm migrating a Rails 3 app to Rails 6 and using the activerecord-reputation-system gem for counting votes.  The app ran without issues before migrating.

When I run the app on localhost, user sign-up, etc works fine, but when I go into the Recommendations section of the app, I get the following error:

**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Recommendations#index
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ...ation_name = 'votes' AND rs_reputations.active = TRUE WHERE**

Recommendations Model:

```
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Recommendations Controller:

```
class RecommendationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_recommendation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @category = ["product", "marketing", "business", "team", "general"]
    @recommendations = Recommendation.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all)
    @product = Recommendation.where(category: "Product").order("votes DESC")
    @marketing = Recommendation.where(category: "Marketing").order("votes DESC")
    @business = Recommendation.where(category: "Business").order("votes DESC")
    @team = Recommendation.where(category: "Team/culture").order("votes DESC")
    @general = Recommendation.where(category: "General").order("votes DESC")
  end
```

and Recommendations Index view:

```
<h3>Recommendations</h3> 


<h5>(<%= link_to new_recommendation_path, "data-no-turbolink" => true do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> New Recommendation
            <% end %>)</h5>


    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
          <th>Submitted</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Votes</th>
      </tr>
      <% @recommendations.each do |recommendation| %>
      <tr>
          <td><%= recommendation.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %><br>
              <small> &nbsp&nbsp by: <strong><%= recommendation.user.name %></strong></td>
          <td><%= recommendation.category %></td>
          <td><%= recommendation.title %></td>
          <td><%= recommendation.description %></td>
          <td>
              <% if current_user && recommendation.has_evaluation?(:votes, current_user) %>
                <%= link_to downvote_recommendation_path(recommendation), method: "post" do %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> 
                <% end %>
              <% else %>
                <%= link_to vote_recommendation_path(recommendation, type: "up"), method: "post" do %>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span> 
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            (<%= recommendation.reputation_for(:votes).to_i %>)
          </td>
      </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
```

The error is being thrown at:

```
<% @recommendations.each do |recommendation| %>
```

From the terminal I see:

```
Started GET "/recommendations" for ::1 at 2019-12-29 10:06:57 -0800
   (3.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by RecommendationsController#index as HTML
  User Load (6.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering recommendations/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Recommendation Load (0.5ms)  SELECT recommendations.*, COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0) AS votes FROM "recommendations" LEFT JOIN rs_reputations ON recommendations.id = rs_reputations.target_id AND rs_reputations.target_type = 'Recommendation' AND rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'votes' AND rs_reputations.active = TRUE WHERE 
  Rendered recommendations/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 3.0ms | Allocations: 1597)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 49ms (ActiveRecord: 17.2ms | Allocations: 21303)



ActionView::Template::Error (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ...ation_name = 'votes' AND rs_reputations.active = TRUE WHERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve by changing controller:

```
@recommendations = Recommendation.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all)
```

to

```
@recommendations = Recommendation.with_reputation(:votes)
```

changing find_with_reputation to with_reputation solved it